Is there a way to register a dll/ocx file by double clicking on it with regsvr32?
As stated in the title, I am looking for a way to register dll/ocx files with regsvr32 by double clicking on them which will automatically launch the command to register them with regsvr32, instead of using the context menu to do it.

would drag and drop be acceptable?

If I have no other choice.
